# Create a list of tuples from list in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, tuples, urllib2

I am using `urllib2` module in python to fetch some kind of information from anchor tags from some urls like `http://www.google.co.in/`, below is the code

```
import urllib2
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.google.co.in/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = page.read()
page.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
   text = tag.text 
   tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
   print '       '.join([text,tag['href']])
```

**result:**

```
Web History       http://www.google.co.in/history/optout?hl=en
Settings       http://www.google.co.in/preferences?hl=en
Sign in       https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.co.in/
Advanced search       http://www.google.co.in/advanced_search?hl=en-IN&authuser=0
Language tools       http://www.google.co.in/language_tools?hl=en-IN&authuser=0
.......................
```

Now its fine but i want to store information as list of tuples like below

```
[('Web History','http://www.google.co.in/history/optout?hl=en'),('Settings','http://www.google.co.in/preferences?hl=en'),('Sign in','https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.co.in/')................]
```

So can anyone let me know how do we format the data coming from for loop as above list of tuples

Comment: Won't a dict be better?? (for storing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[(tag.text, urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])) 
        for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True)]
```

Comment: To say frankly i just want to use this list to render  on a template in some web page, but facing a lot errors like "ascii" codec can't encode characters in postion 0-4: ordinal not in range(128), so what to do in order to escape these kind of errors ?

Comment: @shivakrishna -- I think you should post a separate question about rendering your data, with the relevant code you are using and the exact errors you are getting...

Comment: ofcourse but the questions may contain the same code expect asking about why the errors are displaying right ?, and asked because already u guys know whats going on here.... Anyway will try to create a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a hash and extracting the `items()` tuple from it, this is just a hack:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(IndicatorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    d = dir(indicators)
    b = {}
    for a in d:
        b[a] = a
    b = b.items()
    b.sort()
    self.fields["choice"].choices = b
```

Here dir(indicators) is an array.